# Expression "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" denied access, with an Admin User

Tags: php, controller, fosuserbundle, symfony

I encountered a problem on roles promotion in Symfony3, as the title suggests.

The error is simple :

```
Expression "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" denied access.
```

I promoted the user with

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote (etc.),
```

resulting in :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

in the database.

I also put an annotation on a my controller method :

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
```

And my security.yml looks like this :

```
security:
 encoders:
  MR\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR]
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
  main:
    id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
  dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
  main_login:
    pattern:   ^/login$
    anonymous: true
  main:
    pattern:      ^/
    anonymous:    true
    provider:     main
    form_login:
      login_path: fos_user_security_login
      check_path: fos_user_security_check
    logout:
      path:       fos_user_security_logout
      target:     /
    remember_me:
      secret:     %secret%

access_control:
  #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Do not bother with the visible increments, there are a mere effect of my copy-paste.

I hope I did not missed an obvious point, but I'd prefer it more than a nothing-solved case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the route for the annotation specified as `@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")` in your controller?

Comment: It worked this morning.. I suppose that cache was involved, even if clearing it did not solve the problem yesterday evening.. Sorry for ... that.. ? I don't know what to draw from this. Have a excellent day

Answer (score 1):

@K.F I  "it worked in the morning" => I also had this issue on SF 3.X. It was not a cache problem. Just  simply because I had to disconnect and reconnect to appy the new roles to my user.

Comment: this is not an answer, best delete this and use comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know it wasn't your problem but I solved mine after I realized that I made a mistake in my user promotion... I didn't add the `ROLE_ADMIN` but only `ADMIN`... rookie mistake